# ShellExecute Command doesn't work properly in win10

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I m trying to open a file using shellexecute command my code is

```
ShellExecute(NULL,NULL,itemPath,NULL,NULL,SW_SHOW);
```

or

```
ShellExecute(NULL,L"open",itemPath,NULL,NULL,SW_SHOW);
```

I have used both ways but when I m giving path of a folder it opens a folder but when I m giving a full specified path of a file it doesn't work. 
one thing more if I m giving a hardcode path like for example

```
ShellExecute(NULL,L"open",L"E:\\abc.xlsx",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOW);
```

than it opens this file. can any one explain why it is happening.

Comment: You need to escape backslashes in C++, e.g. `E:\\abc.xlsx`.

Comment: I have used that. ShellExecute(NULL,L"open",L"E:\\abc.xlsx",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOW); this command runs perfectly . problem occurs when I m passing path using variable..

Comment: What type is *itemPath*?

Comment: itempath is of CString type

Comment: If the call to `ShellExecute` appears to work when passing a string literal with the exact same content as a `CString` variable, then more likely than not your variable doesn't hold the value you think it does. At any rate, this isn't nearly enough information to help answer the question. You need to provide a [mcve]. You should also consider calling [ShellExecuteEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx) instead for better error reporting.

Answer (score 2):

`ShellExecute` works correctly, and the defect can be found in your code. The only explanation that makes sense is that `itemPath` is not what you think it is. If it were indeed a pointer to null-terminated character array containing `L"E:\\abc.xlsx"` then `ShellExecute` would behave as you expect.

You can debug the problem by inspecting the content of `itemPath` to find out what it really contains. Were you to have provided an MCVE then we could have been more specific in the diagnosis of the problem.

Finally, `ShellExecute` is deprecated, largely because it provides no good means of reporting failure conditions. You should use `ShellExecuteEx` instead.

Comment: I have debugged it. and itempath contains "E:\abc.xlsx" and itempath is variable of type CString

Comment: If `itemPath == L"E:\\abc.xlsx"` then what you report could not be true. Or do you really believe that `ShellExecute` does not work?

Comment: actually there is bundle of line of code so I can't show the whole code I m getting this path from a file which is encrypted but finally after encryption the  final value itempath contains is E:\abc.xlsx  without double backslashes . same code is working perfectly in win7. but in win 10 it not behave like I m expecting..

Comment: I stand by my answer.

Comment: @KashifMeo: The culprit *has* to be bad content in the `itemPath` variable, it does not contain what you are expecting it to contain. There is no other explanation that fits the symptoms you have described. My guess is the decryption is probably causing extra garbage in the variable that you are not accounting for.

Comment: Sorry one thing which I have forgot to tell you that I my file is locked using filter driver that file will not be shown in explorer.. that locked files are opening in win 7 but not working in win 10. that is what I m asking actually..

Comment: That's a different question completely